# summing numbers stored in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, object, sum

I want to sum a list of numbers stored in a JavaScript object. The object is created and updated using this code:

```
var myscore = $('input[name="Points1"]').val();
scorelist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(playerName + 'scorelist') || '[]');
        scorelist.push(myscore);
        localStorage.setItem(playerName + 'scorelist', JSON.stringify(scorelist));
        $('div.scorecolumn', column).html("Score: <br>" + scorelist.join('<br>') + "<br>");
```

Basically I take whatever is in the column at the time, parse it, add `myscore`, stringify it, join each element with a `<br>` and write the list to the scorecolumn. The list of numbers is saved as an object. My goal is to sum up all the numbers in the object at any given time.

This script is inside of a function that passes in a bunch of parameters which is why some variables look undefined here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

UPDATE:

```
var nicTotalScore = nicScoreList.reduce(function(score, total) {
        return total + score;   
    }, 0);
    console.log(nicTotalScore); //12120
    console.log(nicScoreList); //["12", "12"]
```

UPDATE:
If the score field is left blank when submitted, an empty string " " instead of a score. this is registering as a 0 when the reduce method goes through the array. This doesnt affect the total, but say, for example, i wanted to then find the average score, it throws it off. any ideas there? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `push()` to `scorelist`, I'd be tempted to say it's likely an `Array`.

You could use `reduce()`.

```
var total = scorelist.reduce(function(total, score) {
    return total + +score;
}, 0);
```

Comment: Quite elegant the reduce function.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the reduce function. would you mind explaining more?

Comment: @NicMeiring MDN has good [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: thanks. get it now. answer still concatenating instead of summing though. see updates.

Comment: @NicMeiring You must be storing scores as strings. I'll update my answer.

Comment: one last follow up question if you dont mind. see 2nd update above. thanks!

Comment: @Nic You may need to post the code you're using to calculate the average. Maybe that should be a new question, feel free to link me to it.