# Querying Array of objects using javascript - Helper functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

if you are looking for Get/Delete/Sum/IsExist functions for an array of objects using javascript, I have posted this question and answer for such functions

- Remove Object from an Array using JavaScript
- Is Exist for an Object from an Array using JavaScript
- Select Object from an Array using JavaScript
- Sum Object values in an Array using JavaScript

Comment: Search before posting! And please formulate your question as a question. Or even 4 different ones.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

4 Javascript Helpers

- Remove Object from an Array using JavaScript
- Is Exist for an Object from an Array using JavaScript
- Select Object from an Array using JavaScript
- Sum Object values in an Array using JavaScript

> ```
> var JShelpers = {
>     removeItemFromArray: function (myObjects, prop, valu) {
>         return myObjects.filter(function (item) {
>             return item[prop] !== valu;
>         });
>
>     },
>     isExistInArray: function (myObjects, prop, valu) {
>         var i = myObjects.length;
>         while (i--) {
>             if (myObjects[i][prop] == valu) {
>                 return true;
>             }
>         }
>         return false;
>     },
>     getItemFromArray: function (myObjects, prop, valu) {
>         var i = myObjects.length;
>         while (i--) {
>             if (myObjects[i][prop] == valu) {
>                 return myObjects[i];
>             }
>         }
>         return "";
>     },
>     sumItemInArray: function (myObjects, prop) {
>         var summation = 0;
>         myObjects.forEach(function (item) {
>             summation += parseFloat(item[prop]);
>         });
>         return summation;
>
>     }
> }
> ```

**Example:**
Say you have an array of Employees in a Json Format like this

```
var employeesArray =  [{"Id":1,"Name":"tom","Age":15},{"Id":2,"Name":"Harry","Age":17}];
```

And you want to retrieve employee by his Age not only ID (as common) , 
you can simply call

```
JShelpers.getItemFromArray(employeesArray,"Age",15)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you wrap the second `return` statement in an `else` condition? It looks like you're going to return `true` and `""` no matter what the function result is.

Comment: How ? What do u mean by undocumented ?

Answer (score 0):

1. [How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/array-containsobj-in-javascript)
2. [How do I remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array)
3. [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-array-of-javascript-objects)
4. [summing numbers stored in an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476219/summing-numbers-stored-in-an-array-in-javascript), [sum values of a javascript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627475/sum-values-of-a-javascript-array), [Loop through array and return sum of all values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328000/loop-through-array-and-return-sum-of-all-values)

Btw, your question doesn't have much to do with [JSON](http://json.org/), and naught with jQuery.

Comment: I have used this function to query JSON returned array of objects

Comment: its querying JSON object [JavaScript Object Notation]

Comment: [No, you're not](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: Im using it to query JSON objects, if it has an array

Answer (score 0):

Just use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).

Remove from a simple array:

```
var newList = _.without(list, 'hello', 'world'); // Remove any instance of 'hello' and 'world'
```

Remove from an array of objects:

```
var toRemove = _.where(list, {title: 'hello', subtitle: 'world'});
var newList = _.difference(list, toRemove);
```

Exists in array:

```
var exists = _.contains(list, value);
```

Get item from array:

```
var item = _.find(list, function(i){ i === value }); // For simple types
var item = _.findWhere(list, {title: 'hello', subtitle: 'world'}); // For complex types
```

Sum items:

```
var sum = _.reduce(list, function(start, num){ return start + num; }, 0);
```

And A LOT more.